# why doesnt res.sendFile load images

Tags: node.js

why dont images load in res.sendFile ? Here is the server.js file and the red.html file is below. If i load the red.html file by itself the picture shows accurately

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/server'));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
   console.log("hello");
res.sendFile('C:/Users/juniper/Documents/practiceCode/red.html');
});

app.post('/', function(req,res) {
   res.send('post it all');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
```

red.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>red screen</title>
     </head>
  <body>
   <img src="red.png" usemap="#redmap">
   <map name="redmap">
   <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,1000,900" href="index.html">
  </map>
  <style>
    img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }
    map {
    position: absolute;
    }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP sends single "files". You have handlers for exactly 1 URL (`/`). When the browser goes and requests `/red.png` from your server, you have no handlers for this, so it gets no data.

Comment: so how do i handle it?